# Where can I find a Windows 10 driver for an integrated Reneas USB 3.0 controller?

Tags: drivers, windows-10-upgrade, sony-vaio

I'm trying to fix a Vaio laptop (from Sony) that has a Renesas USB controller built-in.  After upgrading to Windows 10, the drivers no longer work.  They aren't signed.  Sony doesn't support that model for Windows 10 and only offers Windows 7 compatible drivers.  Renesas only offers sample drivers for developers.  Is there someplace I can find signed working drivers for the Renesas USB 3.0 controller?  Just in case, there are two versions of it, a 2 port and 4 port versions.

The computer is a Sony Vaio, model VPCF136FM.  The link to the driver on the Sony support site says it has a Renesas® Electronics USB 3.0 Host Controller.

Comment: If you could tell us the specific controller it has we might be able to help.

Comment: Depending on which chipset you have get the driver from here: http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=353&func=select&id=196&lang=en

Comment: Strange. Renesas controllers should be supported by the general XHCI driver in Windows 10. How is it shown under Device Manager? Is it telling you that an inapproriate driver is being used or indeed no driver?

Comment: @Tom I don't have it anymore, but it was trying to use a generic Intel driver.  Knowing to use the general XHCI driver might be enough, thank you.

Comment: Got the same problem. Looks like the Renesas USB 3.0 controller used in the Sony VPCF1 laptop is not supported by Windows 10. Annoying since there's only one USB2 port.